# how to set BufferedLogs to Off in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

Please show me how to set BufferedLogs to Off

I found httpd config: sudo find / -name 'httpd.conf' and can not find keyword "BufferedLogs" in file I found

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Default:    BufferedLogs Off

See, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

So if it is not found in httpd.conf BufferdLogs are Off.